# trying to send basic nodemailer email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to insert some test code with hard-coded email data directly into my nodemailer server.js file to get started with a basic working example. See the "test code" section at the following url:

http://jsbin.com/sibubi/1/edit?html,js,console

Server.js loads without issue without the test code. However, an error occurs when the "test code" section is included. It complains about "unsupported configuration" and suggests a downgrade but I copied the test code from the nodemailer website. Any idea what the issue might be and how to fix? Here's the error:

http://jsbin.com/kehofe/1/edit

Answer (score 4):

package.json

```
"nodemailer": "~1.4.0",
"nodemailer-smtp-transport":"~1.0.3"
```

install them

Your controller code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport((smtpTransport({
  host: YOUR_HOST,
  secureConnection: false, // use SSL
  port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
  auth: {
    user: YOUR_USERNAME,
    pass: YOUR_PASSWORD
  }
})));
```

You need to change the SMTP configuration as mentioned above. And the rest is same as 0.7 version code.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like nodemailer 1.0 has breaking changes so 0.7 must be used instead: http://www.nodemailer.com/

**Message posted on nodemailer as of 12/17/15:**

Do not upgrade Nodemailer from 0.7 or lower to 1.0 as there are breaking changes. You can continue to use the 0.7 branch as long as you like. See the documentation for 0.7 [here](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/blob/0.7/README.md).

Comment: I want ot use latest version, I'm not upgrading, I simply started using it at lastest version !