# Nodemailer whit GMail SMTP OAuth2 autentication is getting me 'Invalid status code 401'

Tags: node.js, email, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, nodemailer

I'm  trying to make a simple mail sender using Nodemailer 3, the GMail API whit OAuth2 autentication.

Here's my script:

```
var serverConfig  = {
  gmail: {
      client_user : 'my@email.com',
      client_id : '349...myClientId',
      secret : 'mysecret..123jd123',
      refresh_token : 'x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-reZuEMeSuJaSERmCVY',
      access_token : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      expires: '3599'
  }
}

// 3LO authentication https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#example-3
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: serverConfig.gmail.client_user,
    clientId: serverConfig.gmail.client_id,
    clientSecret: serverConfig.gmail.secret,
    refreshToken: serverConfig.gmail.refresh_token
  },
});

module.exports = {
    "send": function(_from,_to,_subject,_html,_text){
      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      var mailOptions = {
          from: _from,
          to: _to, // list of receivers
          subject: _subject, // Subject line
          html: _html, // html body
          text: _text // plain text body
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message ' + info.messageId + ' sent: %s' + info.response);
      })
  }


}
```

When I force the access_token in the auth object, the email is sent without any problem. But, when I don't specify the `access_token`, only de `refresh_token`, I'm getting this error:

```
{ Error: Invalid status code 401
    at ClientRequest.req.on.res (/myproject/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/fetch/index.js:193:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:474:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
  type: 'FETCH',
  sourceUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  code: 'EAUTH',
  command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

Comment: i make a [copy of this question in Stack Overflow español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54470/nodemailer-con-gmail-smtp-y-autenticaci%C3%B3n-oauth2-me-devuelve-invalid-status-cod?noredirect=1#comment97072_54470)

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Having the same problem.  I also don't know how you get the `refreshToken`.  Isn't that sent in the response?

Comment: Not really. I decide to use the simple SMPT authentication.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I got it to work with OAuth2 after banging my head against a wall for hours: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working/43202668#43202668

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late, but just answering here incase someone comes across the same issue. My problem rectified when the refreshToken was reset. [This article](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/nodemailer-service-in-node-js-using-smtp-and-xoauth2-7c638a39a37e) gives great instructions for the whole process

Comment: article gone :(

Comment: can you repost the artiucle link if possible ?

Comment: sorry guys the author if that article has taken it down. Hopefully these two links can you help
https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/

https://community.nodemailer.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by going to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials, selecting the correct OAuth 2.0 Client ID, and choosing "Reset Secret" at the top. This revoked my old secret and generated a new one, which I then used in the OAuth Playground to exchange for a refresh token. I put the new Client Secret and Refresh Token in the auth object for nodemailer and it started working again.