# TypeError: nodemailer.createTransport is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules, nodemailer

I am trying to implement nodemailer in my nodejs app to send emails.

Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require('node-mailer');

var app = express();
app.post('/contact/send', function(req, res) {
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'myEmailIdHere',
        pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'myName <myEmailIdHere>',
    to: 'myOtherEmailIdHere',
    subject: 'Website Submission',
    text: 'You have a submission with the following details... Name: ' + req.body.name + ' Email: ' + req.body.email + ' Message: ' + req.body.message,
    html: '<p>You have a submission with the following details...</p><ul><li>Name: ' + req.body.name + '</li><li>Email: ' + req.body.email + '</li><li>Message: ' + req.body.message + '</li></ul>'
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        console.log('Message Sent: ' + info.response);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
})
```

After submitting the form, i am getting the error as

"TypeError: nodemailer.createTransport is not a function"

Can someone help me figure out how to make the code work with nodemailer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

Answer (score 4):

Seems you have done

```
npm install node-mailer --save
```

which is this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mailer

While you are trying to follow instructions for this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer

For your code to work do

```
npm install nodemailer --save
```

Then require module as

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
```

Do not put hyphen between node-mailer it is a different module.

Comment: I had this line in my dependancies in package.json "node-mailer": "*"

Comment: That's because you might have installed node-mailer first but as @sidgate as you mentioned nodemailer is working fine, so that's good enough. Also you might want to take a look at this official [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/about/) of node mailer for any further clarifications regarding nodemailer.

Comment: i just changed it from node-mailer to nodemailer. now it is not showing the error. but i still haven't got the mail on my email id. Is there some other error?

Comment: It seems, it was just slow internet. it's working perfectly fine now.

Comment: for me, I installed "node-mailer" instead of "nodemailer"

Answer (score 1):

[`nodemailer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) and `node-mailer` are two different modules. You should use the right one.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

Also, make sure nodemailer is installed using `npm i`

Comment: Sure, I'll try it again by requiring nodemailer.

Comment: Yes, It Worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: now it doesn't show the error, but the mail is still not getting sent.

Comment: any error/response? also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working

Comment: it said "connection timeout" and then it showed me "Message Sent: 250 2.0.0 OK". but I didn't receive the mail on my gmail account.

Comment: It seems, it was just slow internet. it's working perfectly fine now.