# Nodemailer emails not being received by gmail

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

Nodemailer works fine when sending to email addresses on multiple different Domains. But when im sending a mail to a gmail adress, Gmail dont receive this mail.

what i have to Change?

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTranspor({

      host: 'test.de',
      port: 25,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: 'default.smtp@test.de',
        pass: 'test'
      }
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working/26196619 ?

Comment: Gmail is probably thinking your message is spam. What error do you get when sending the email?

Comment: i dont get any error. ist just not in the gmail-postbox

Comment: you might want to have a look at this github issues thread in the nodemailer repo https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/677

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a name attribute, this worked for me.