# How to send email in Firebase for free?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm aware that Firebase doesn't allow you to send emails using 3rd party email services. So the only way is to send through Gmail.

So I searched the internet for ways, so here's a snippet that works and allows me to send email without cost.

```
export const shareSpeechWithEmail = functions.firestore
  .document("/sharedSpeeches/{userId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    // const userId = context.params.userId;
    // const data = snapshot.data();
    const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
      `smtps://${process.env.USER_EMAIL}:${process.env.USER_PASSWORD}@smtp.gmail.com`
    );


    const mailOptions = {
      to: "test@gmail.com",
      subject: `Message test`,
      html: `<p><b>test</b></p>`
    };
    try {
      return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  });
```

I want to create a template, so I used this package called `email-templates` for nodemailer.
But the function doesn't get executed in Firebase Console and it doesn't show an error and shows a warning related to "billing".

```
export const shareSpeechWithEmail = functions.firestore
  .document("/sharedSpeeches/{userId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const email = new Email({
      send: true,
      preview: false,
      views: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../src/emails")
        // root: path.resolve(__dirname, "emails")
      },
      message: {
        // from: "<noreply@domain.com>"
        from: process.env.USER_EMAIL
      },
      transport: {
        secure: false,
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.USER_EMAIL,
          pass: process.env.USER_PASSWORD
        }
      }
    });

    try {
      return email.send({
        template: "sharedSpeech",
        message: {
          to: "test@gmail.com",
          subject: "message test"
        },
        locals: {
          toUser: "testuser1",
          fromUser: "testuser2",
          title: "Speech 1",
          body: "<p>test using email <b>templates</b></p>"
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 11):

You can definitely send emails using third party services and Cloud Functions, as long as your project is on the Blaze plan.  The official provided samples even suggest that "if switching to Sendgrid, Mailjet or Mailgun make sure you enable billing on your Firebase project as this is required to send requests to non-Google services."

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/quickstarts/email-users

The key here, no matter which email system you're using, is that you really need to upgrade to the Blaze plan in order to make outgoing connections.

Comment: Let's say i enabled blaze plan and send an email using sendgrid. Would it cost something even if i haven't reached a quota in their free plan?

Comment: If you have billing question, please consult the [pricing guide](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).  If that doesn't have enough information, please reach out to Firebase support for billing questions. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 8):

you can send emails by using nodemailer:

```
npm install nodemailer cors

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp();

/**
* Here we're using Gmail to send 
*/
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'yourgmailaccount@gmail.com',
        pass: 'yourgmailaccpassword'
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        // getting dest email by query string
        const dest = req.query.dest;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'Your Account Name <yourgmailaccount@gmail.com>', // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
            to: dest,
            subject: 'test', // email subject
            html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">test it!!</p>
                <br />
            ` // email content in HTML
        };

        // returning result
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if(erro){
                return res.send(erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sended');
        });
    });    
});
```

See also [here](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e)

Set Security-Level to avoid error-messages:
Go to : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
set the Access for less secure apps setting to Enable

Refer [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this solution. I was able to send email with just nodemailer but when i use email-templates package that uses nodemailer it doesn't work, i wonder why that is?

Comment: It seems to be a security problem. See above.

Comment: yup, i've already turned on less secured apps. But still same error

Comment: Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 534-5.7.14  
This error occurred :( 
I was grant access for less secure apps (in Gmail) but still, it was blocked access

Comment: This is working with app passwords.. No need to turn on access for less secure apps. ( go to account settings and create an app password and place that password as the email password)

Comment: When that function is triggered ? i wanna triggered when new document is created

Answer (score 5):

Call a `sendMail()` cloud function directly via `functions.https.onCall(..)` :

> As @Micha mentions don't forget to enable Less Secure Apps for the outgoing email: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'supportabc@gmail.com',
        pass: '11112222'
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    console.log('enter exports.sendMail, data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

    const recipientEmail = data['recipientEmail'];
    console.log('recipientEmail: ' + recipientEmail);

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'Abc Support <Abc_Support@gmail.com>',
        to: recipientEmail,
        html:
           `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Thanks for signing up</p>
            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Stay tuned for more updates soon</p>
            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Best Regards,</p>
            <p style="font-size: 12px;">-Support Team</p>
          ` // email content in HTML
    };

    mailOptions.subject = 'Welcome to Abc';

    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
        console.log('email sent to:', recipientEmail);
        return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
       
            return resolve({
                result: 'email sent to: ' + recipientEmail
            });
        }));
    });
});
```

Thanks also to: [Micha's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938290/2162226)

Answer (score 1):

You can send for free with Firebase extensions and Sendgrid:

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-extension-trigger-email-5802800bb9ea

Answer (score 0):

DEPRECATED: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Use "Sign in with App Passwords": https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en to create an app password.

follow the steps in the link then use the given password with your user in mailTransport:

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'bunchofletterspassword'
    }
});
```