# Express js backend to send email from contact page using firebase hosting works running locally but not on URL at Firebase-deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I have created a backend server using express and deployed to firebase. which allows me to receive emails from my contact page in my portfolio.

I am able to receive emails when I run both client and backend server locally. But when I deploy to firebase and tried with the firebase app URL, it's not working. Then I tried hosting my app in Github and tried the contact page so that request is from SSL page(https). But still, I get error 500
I tried the solution mentioned and didn't work
[sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working)

My express js codes

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const path = require("path");
const sendMail = require("./mail");
const log = console.log;
var cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

// data parsing
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/email", (req, res) => {
  // expect to receive some data from client
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;
  log("Data", req.body);
  sendMail(email, name, message, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Error" });
    } else {
      res.json({ message: "success", data });
    }
  });
  //email, name, text
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views", "index.html"));
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**mail.js**

```
const mailGun = require("nodemailer-mailgun-transport");

const auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: "xxxxxxxxx",
    domain: "xxxxxxxxx"
  }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth));
const sendMail = (email, name, message, callBack) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: email,
    to: "faizhameedv@gmail.com",
    subject: `your website mail from ${name}`,
    text: message
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      callBack(err, null);
    } else {
      callBack(null, data);
      console.log("Message Sent!!");
    }
  });
};

module.exports = sendMail;
```

It works when I run locally using `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` and then when I deploy it to firebase which is successful. But I cant req the new URL given by firebase with `/email`

Comment: When on firebase is the log `log("Data", req.body);` printing something? Or straight away call is not happening. I guess if so, you'll need to open the same port on firebase on which this express server is listening. If logs are printing, then please tell me what it is..

Comment: How to see the log when its on production and i can see this log when running server locally only