# Receive bounced emails using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer, email-bounces

I am new to the SMTP related concepts. I am currently developing a nodejs email client using Nodemailer. In which, I am unable to receive the bounce back emails (NDRs). My queries below,

1. To achieve this should I configure DSN or envelope? I think I'm confusing myself with the dsn and envelope options.
2. How does nodemailer get the bounced email? Any separate configuration needed for this? Or any event listener?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working. You may get your solution.
Try setting Access for less secure apps setting to Enable and then check for bounce back emails