# Using nodemailer to send emails not working

Tags: javascript, express, email, nodemailer

I am creating a project with authentication and after registration this function is supposed to call

```
exports.sendEmail = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const mailText = `<body style="text-align: center"><h1>Name Of Company</h1><p>This email was automatically sent to you to confirm your account at<b>Name of Company</b><br /><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Please press on this link to confirm your account</a></p></body>`;
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "example@gmail.com",
        pass: "password",
      },
    });

    const options = {
      from: "example@gmail.com",
      to: "user@gmail.com",
      subject: "Confirm Your Email",
      html: mailText,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: err,
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: "Sent: " + info.response,
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error");
  }
}
```

But the email is not sending and neither the try or catch are sending anything back.
I have also turned on the less secure apps in gmail
How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `error` doesn't have a message? If you are, does it even get into this function?

Comment: Try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working

Comment: Did you check any of the code in your try is executed?